# VMware SVGA driver on Windows 95 fails to install

Tags: vmware-workstation, windows-95, vmware-tools

So one day I decided to try out Windows 95 in VMware Workstation (I'm using 11.1.0). I install VMware Tools, however there is an error:

```
This program has performed an illegal operation and will be shut down.
If the problem persists, contact the program vendor.
```

I am able to install VMware Tools by running the `VMware Tools.msi` file on the drive, however there is (yet) another error.

```
Setup failed to install the SVGA driver automatically. This driver will have to be installed manually. Instructions for how to do this will appear at the end of the installation.
```

After I finish the installation, nothing shows up, except a prompt to reboot.

I tried using the Hardware Installation Wizard to install the driver at `C:\PROGRA~1\VMWARE\VMWARE~1\DRIVERS\VIDEO`. It didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: It sounds like the VM Tools drivers are not supported by Windows 95 which isn't shocking in the slightest.  You won't be able to install VM Tools drivers if you want to use Windows 95.

Comment: If there are no answers, I can suggest using the [generic VESA driver](http://bearwindows.boot-land.net/vbe9x.htm) instead.

Comment: I always found [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) to be best for emulating Windows 95.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Windows 95 with VMware Workstation 12 Player.

1. Set Monitor type: In Display Properties change Monitor Type to some Super VGA resolution such as "Super VGA 1024x768"
2. Install VMware video driver.

   - In Device Manager select *Other Devices* -> *PCI VGA-Compatible Display Adapter*.
   - Select *Driver* tab.
   - Select *Change Driver*.
   - Select *Display Adapter*.
   - Select *Have Disk*.
   - Browse to `C:\Program~1\vmware\vmware~1\drivers\video`
   - Note file name "vmx_svga.inf" should be selected.
   - Select *OK*.
   - Note "Models: VMWare SVGA II" should be selected.
   - Select *OK*.
   - Select *OK*.

You should now be able to set the display resolution up to that of the monitor resolution selected. For example if the Monitor Resolution is 1024x768 you can select the resolution of 1024x768 or less. Note the default Color Palette will now be True Color (32-bit).